# How can I generate plain old code from a text file on save with visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, code-generation

Many of the features in visual studio rely on editing a markup file and then saving it to auto-generate POC in C#.

For example, editing and saving a database `*.dbml` file will generate a `*.designer.cs` file that you can call from POC. It's also seen with ASP.Net `*.aspx` files, generating an `*.aspx.designer.cs` upon save so that the controls can be accessed in the codebehind files.

Is it possible to leverage this functionality in my own software so that I can define my own text files in CSV, JSON, or XML format and specify rules for generating code upon saving the file?

Answer (score 2):

The Visual Studio feature to generate code is called [T4 Templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx).

Comment: I've seen that before, but thought its use was for something else. Is there an in-built way to trigger a template generation when the input file is changed?

Comment: I haven't used it, but I guess you can set the "Custom Tool" in the properties of your input file. Then it will be regenerated whenever the input file is changed.